# After upgrading to Windows 10 the Invantive Control for Exact Online add-in is gone in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, invantive-control

My PC was upgraded from Windows 7 to Windows 10. This was done using formatting the hard disk and then re-installing all software.

I used to have a Developers ribbon in which I could disable/enable the COM-addin of Invantive. The Developers in Excel is now missing. Neither can I find the COM-addin in File -> Options -> Add-ins -> COM -> Go.

I've tried running setup.exe from our download location:
    https://download.invantive.com/environments/NUMBER/stable/clickonce/invantive-control-for-excel-2016R1/setup.exe

When I run this setup.exe, I get a:

> The following Microsoft Office-solution can not be installed due to a
>   general error in the installation program: install.vsto.
>
> 0x8007007E

How can I re-instantiate Invantive Control for Excel?

BTW. The Invantive Query Tool for Exact Online runs fine, so Microsoft .NET is installed in the correct version.

Comment: Please check that VSTO is installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've installed Microsoft VSTO from [Microsoft site](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/download/details.aspx?id=48217), restarted the PC and now setup.exe runs after confirming that I want to install the software.

It seems that the VSTO presence check in Invantive which worked on Windows 7 doesn't work on Windows 10.